# Customization of native android components in Titanium appcelerotor

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I am experienced android developer but newbie in Tiatanium appcelerator.
I want to develop an android app using Titanium Appcelerator.
My questions are as follows.

1. Can we customize the native android components(like RelativeLayout,Button,etc..) ?  for example I want to develop some custom view like pull-to-refreshlistview by extending ListView class or I want my own custom ImageView by extending the ImageView class is it possible with appcelerator platform?
2. Can I create a my own mediaplayer/videoplayer using appcelerator platform?

If I can leverage the native android components like views by extending them.Then any demo/sample will be highly appreciated.

**NOTE :: I am using Titanium Studio IDE to develop my android apps.**

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can do all the above mentioned things.
As appcelerator provides you severals API's where you can achieve the desired.
you can create a a view and set its layout to relative etc.

You can create a pull to refresh feature in android too. here is the link [Pull to refresh-Android](https://gist.github.com/903895)

And yes you can create your own media player with Appcelerator. I have made it.

to see the examples, download the titanium studio and download the sample App - kitchen sink. In this sample App you can see all the cool stuff Appcelerator can do.

you can download the sample App from the Titanium studio or you can refer this link for [KitchenSink](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/)

Hope that helped. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot ajit.
Hey Ajit can you tell me some tutorial which can help me to delve in the titanium appcelerator world,

Comment: Hey Ajit,
As you have mentioned you have created your own media player can you Guide me how to do it since for my android app I want my own mediaplayer.
Thanks .......

Comment: The best place to start learning Titanium is the appcelerator docs. here is the link http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/guide

Comment: My media player consist of 3 buttons and then you just have to use Appcelerator media API to play or to leverage the facility of media player